# Correct way of synchronized task while not locking object for the whole time?

Tags: java

So I have multiple Java Objects and at some time during the execution a thread will ask for its ID. When it does that for the first time I Want to make sure it also starts storing the object session in a database, however I don't want to lock the whole object during the database call, just the thread that's currently calling it.

Here's the current code I'm using, will that work?

```
public String getId() {
    boolean shouldAddTaskToSql = false;
    synchronized (this) {
        if(!this.hasBeenAddedToSql) {
            shouldAddTaskToSql = true;
            this.hasBeenAddedToSql = true;
        }
    }
    if(shouldAddTaskToSql) {
        try {
    new MySQLTaskCreateSession().runQuery(new Object[] { this });
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (QueryCanceledException e) { }
    }
    return this.state_id;
}
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is not making multiple threads lock because a single one is writing the session to a databse, I need multiple threads to be able to call getId() while only making one of them insert to the database. (while the db call is being made other threads can still call getId() without waiting for the synchronized lock to release.

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: So what happens when thread #2 comes in, right on the heels of thread #1, and simply does the `return this.state_id` before the `runQuery` method completes? I guess my question really is: What does `MySQLTaskCreateSession.runQuery` do? The name implies is runs a *query*, i.e. a `SELECT` statement, but your question text implies it does an `INSERT`. Note that, while `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE`, and `SELECT` are all SQL *statements*, only the `SELECT` statement is a *query*.

Comment: Yeah it seems to work, just wondering if it's the right way to go about it, or does it seem fine?

Comment: @Andreas the runQuery does a database insert call. The state_id is a random string that's created in the object constructor, so it always stays the same. Thank you!